# Log4j 2 is not logging from executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j2

I'm confused. I am using log4j 2 for logging and everything works fine, when I launch my program with eclipse. But after packing the sources to a jar there are no logs written to console or files.

Here's the jar's manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: s
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_45
Class-Path: settings settings/log4j2.xml lib/poi-3.9.ja
 r lib/commons-codec-1.5.jar lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.29.jar lib/l
 og4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar lib/log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.4
Main-Class: application.Start
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

My log4j2.xml is here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %C{1}.%M{1}:%L{1} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <RollingFile  name="app" fileName="log/app.log" bufferedIO="true" filePattern="log/app-%i.log.gz">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %C{1}.%M{1}:%L{1} - %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500 KB"/>
      </Policies>
    </RollingFile > 
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="app" level="trace">
        <AppenderRef ref="app" />
    </Logger>  
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

All the other jars in lib are bound correctly and the application works well. What I'm doing wrong with log4j ?

Comment: why are you using a release candidate for logging? "log4j-core-2.0-rc1"

Comment: Is your JAR meant to be a "self contained JAR"?

Comment: @ArnaudPotier log4j 2.0 has not shipped yet. The latest you can get (at time of writing this) for log4j2 is rc1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now a solution: The problem is my classpath. I've changed it from

```
Class-Path: settings
```

to

```
Class-Path: settings/
```

It suffices to state the directory where the xml is in.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with `-Dlog4j.debug=true` ([details](http://www.jroller.com/holy/entry/troubleshooting_logging_configuration_log4j_commons)). log4j will then print a lot of information about the configuration as it loads it.

With log4j 2, try `<Configuration status="DEBUG">`.

Comment: I'm using log4j 2 and configured it according to this documentation: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html. My configuration works fine when i start the project from eclipse, so I think the problem is something with the classpath of the jar. If I add -Dlog4j.debug=true also no output appears.

Comment: I've changed it to <Configuration status="DEBUG"> but it has no effect

Comment: That tells me that your configuration isn't picked up by log4j 2 at all. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to enable debug mode globally: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#troubleshooting

Comment: after correcting the classpath of the jar, <Configuration status="DEBUG"> has effect :) thx for your help